# How to get the listview loaded in the form only after the button is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

In my project, I need to get the listview containing the data from the back end, If I place the listview in the form and upon clicking a button I can load data, but the requirement is initially the listview should be hidden or not present there, only on clicking the button the listview should be viewed with data. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the List View's property `Visible = False`in the properity window.

Within the button click event handler set it to true;

```
listView1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Thank you... It worked, I have set the property to false and then used the code the you provided. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `Visible` Property. At the form load, you set it to `false` and then in the `button_click`

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use listView1.Hide(); initially in Form constructor

And on button click You should use listView1.show()